# Perm Gem issue in grails application

Tags: java, tomcat, grails, java-opts

I was create a grails(2.1) application and deploy it on tomcat server. But I am getting Perm Gem space error.

I have some idea to ignore this error by setting `JAVA_OPTS`. But I didn't have any rights to access `Tomcat/bin` directory.

So, anybody have idea for ignore this error without accessing `Tomcat/bin` directory

Answer (score 0):

You can [disable grails auto-recompile feature](http://www.grails.org/FAQ#Q%3a%20OMG%20I%20get%20OutOfMemoryErrors%20or%20PermGen%20Space%20errors%20when%20running%20Grails%20in%20development%20mode.%20What%20do%20I%20do?), if it is not important.

```
$ grails -Ddisable.auto.recompile=true run-app
```